# why smarty not considering session variables?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

Why smarty 3 doesn't consider codeIgniter session variables:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('userId', $res['id']);  // this doesn't work 

$_SESSION['userId']=$res['id']; // this works.
```

I am accessing this in smarty as:

```
{$smarty.session.userId}
```

Answer (score 3):

CI (!!!) does not use the PHP super-global $_SESSION...

Have a read here on a nice way to expose CI's session to Smarty.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/forums/viewthread/110540/#571279

Comment: I think you mean CodeIgniter doesn't use the PHP super-global :)

Answer (score 0):

In codeIgniter

```
$this->session->set_userdata()
```

function save the data in cookie,So you can not get data by session.

Comment: What about this destroying session , only deletes cookies:
            $this->session->unset_userdata('userId');
            $this->session->sess_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this ways:

1. In your controllers like this:

   $data['session']=$this->session->userdata;
   $this->smarty_parser->parse("smarty.php", $data);

Or if you don’t whant to do it each time in your controllers, you can move this to your smarty wrapper class.

2. In your smarty wrapper (smarty_parser.php) like this:

   function parse($template, $data, $return = FALSE)
       {
           if ($template == '') return FALSE;
           $CI =& get_instance();

   ```
       /* here it goes */
       $data['session']=$CI->session->userdata;


      ...
   }
   ```

Then you can access all your session data in templates by using

```
{$session.session_id}
```